# I'm working part time as an intern, and my supervisor is leaving. Is it too late to ask about a full time position?

Tags: management, internship, manager

I've been working full time during the summer and part time during the semester under my current supervisor for around half a year. I'm currently a senior in college.

She is leaving in 2 weeks. I was wondering if I will be able to stay at the company as an intern. Should I ask her about the possibility of a full time position before she leaves, or is it too late at this point?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I ask her about the possibility of a full time position before
>   she leaves, or is it too late at this point?

Yes, you should ask her.

Also ask her who you should talk to in her absence. Perhaps she knows who her replacement will be. Or perhaps she'll have you talk with her manager.

If you have had a good relationship with her, ask if she will put in a good word for you, or write a letter of recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

If your boss is good, they will have thought about these things and try to make sure that you land in a good place. But all in all after they leave they don't have that much influence over this anymore.

So, yes do talk to your boss right now and see where you stand.